# How to import all images from an ACR repository to another ACR in different tenant

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry

**Scenario:** I have 4 repos in an ACR(azure container registry) with multiple images in each repo. I want to move all the repos and all images in it to a different ACR(azure container registry)
**What I have Done:** I have used below command to import a single image in an ACR(azure container registry) repo to another ACR repo.

```
az acr import \
  --name myregistry \
  --source sourceregistry.azurecr.io/sourcerrepo:tag \
  --image targetimage:tag \
  --username <SP_App_ID> \
  --password <SP_Passwd>
```

**Problem:** The above command only imports a single image based on the tag given.

**Solution Needed:** What I want to achieve is to import all the image inside a single repo of an ACR to a different ACR.

Please let me know if anyone have any solution for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whipped up this script using pwsh and az cli:

```
$SourceAcrName="source ACR Name"
$DestinationAcrName="destination ACR Name"

$Repos= az acr repository list --name $SourceAcrName | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($repo in $Repos) {
    $Tags = az acr repository show-tags -n $SourceAcrName --repository $repo | ConvertFrom-Json
    foreach ($tag in $Tags) {
        az acr import -r $SourceAcrName -n $DestinationAcrName --source "${repo}:${tag}" --no-wait
    }
}
```

It will copy all repositories and tags in the ACR to the destination ACR.
the `--no-wait` parameter allows the tasks to run in the background in Azure, so you don't have to wait for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

got @Maraudingas script and made a slight change
That is how it worked for me

```
$SourceAcrName="##"
$DestinationAcrName="##"

$Repos= az acr repository list --name $SourceAcrName --username ## --password ##| ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($repo in $Repos) {
$Tags = az acr repository show-tags -n $SourceAcrName --repository $repo --username ## --password ##| ConvertFrom-Json
foreach ($tag in $Tags) {
    az acr import -n $DestinationAcrName --source "${SourceAcrName}.azurecr.io/${repo}:${tag}" --no-wait --username ## --password ##
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also used the script above and made some changes, this only copies the 10 latest tags from each repository:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

srcRegistry="srcacr"
dstRegistry="dstacr"
repos=$(az acr repository list --name "${srcRegistry}"  --output json)

while read repo; do
  printf "Importing repo %s\n" "${repo}"
  tags=$(az acr repository show-tags -n "${srcRegistry}" --repository "${repo}" --output json --orderby time_desc)

  while read tag; do
    printf "  tag %s\n" "${tag}"
    az acr import -n "${dstRegistry}" --source "${srcRegistry}.azurecr.io/${repo}:${tag}"  --username <source-username> --password "<source-password>" --no-wait
  done <<<"$(echo ${tags} | jq -r '.[0:10] | .[]')"

done <<<"$(echo ${repos} | jq -r '.[]')"
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited @Maraudingas script so that can be used to import repositories from container registry which is on another Subscription.

```
$SourceAcrName="my-source-registry"
$SourceAcr="/subscriptions/########-####-####-####-########/resourceGroups/########/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/my-source-registry"
$DestinationAcrName="my-destination-registry"
$DestinationAcr="/subscriptions/########-####-####-####-########/resourceGroups/########/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/my-destination-registry"

$UserNameSource="my-source-registry"
$PasswordSource="########################"

$UserNameDestination="my-destination-registry"
$PasswordDestination="########################"

$Repos= az acr repository list --name $SourceAcrName --username $UserNameSource --password $PasswordSource | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($repo in $Repos) {
    Write-Output $repo;

    $Tags = az acr repository show-tags -n $SourceAcrName --repository $repo --username $UserNameSource --password $PasswordSource | ConvertFrom-Json
    foreach ($tag in $Tags) {
        Write-Output $tag;
        az acr import --name $DestinationAcrName --registry $SourceAcr --source "${repo}:${tag}" --image "${repo}:${tag}" --username $UserNameSource --password $PasswordSource
    }
}
```

*NOTE: First select your **destination** subscription:*

```
az account set --subscription ########-####-####-####-########
```