# Migrate Gitlab registry To Azure Container Registry

Tags: gitlab, registry, azure-container-registry

I want to move my Gitlab Registry to Azure Container registry

I found this command to Import from a non-Azure private container registry
but it's for a single image not the whole registry

```
az acr import \
  --name myregistry \
  --source docker.io/sourcerepo/sourceimage:tag \
  --image sourceimage:tag \
  --username <username> \
  --password <password>
```

Is there a way to move all registry images at once ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if below commands can give an idea to work around:

Here try to use the Azure CLI commands `az acr repository list` and `az acr repository show-tags`  to include image tags in a loop.

( we can initiate [Login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication?tabs=azure-cli) at the start  )

```
SOURCE_REGISTRY=myregistry
TARGET_REGISTRY=targetregistry

# Get list of source repositories
REPOS =  $(az acr repository list \  --name $SOURCE_REGISTRY --output tsv)

# Enumerate tags and import to target registry
for repo in $REPOS; do
    TAGS= $(az acr repository show-tags --name $OURCE_REGISTRY  --repository $repo --output tsv);

    for tag in $TAGS; do
        echo "Importing $repo:$tag";
        az acr import --name $TARGET_REGISTRY --source $SOURCE_REGISTRY /$repo":"$tag  --username <username>   --password <password>  ;
    done
done
```

or Azure PowerShell equivalents  as in Reference:  [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/manual-regional-move#import-registry-content-in-target-registry)
and  almost similar to  [Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67749357/how-to-import-all-images-from-an-acr-repository-to-another-acr-in-different-tena)

**References:**

1. [Moving docker images from one container registry to another | by Paulo Gomes | Medium](https://medium.com/@pjbgf/moving-docker-images-from-one-container-registry-to-another-2f1f1631dc49)
2. [container-registry-import-images | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-import-images?tabs=azure-cli#import-from-a-non-azure-private-container-registry)

Comment: thanks i'll try this