# Migrating Gitlab Container Registry To Azure Contaner Registry

Tags: azure, gitlab, azure-container-registry

I am trying to migrate Gitlab-ce Container Registry to Azure Container Registry :
the command im using :

```
az acr import \
  --name acr name\
  --source gitlab/repo/repo/tag
  --username ****\
  --password *****
```

and it works.

what im trying to do now since there is no direct migration in the internet is to create a script to automate the migration process

my idea is like this :

```
# Get list of projects,repos and tags
repos = i couldn't find a command to list the repos
for project in project do: 
    repos = get all repos
    for repo in repos do: 
        tags = get all tags 
        az acr import \
        --name acr name\
        --source gitlab/$project/$repo/$tag
        --username ****\
        --password *****
    done
done
```

The Problem is i couldn't find any command to list project,repos or tags using gitlab command line
is there another way to automate the migration if i couldn't find the commands ??

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below commands can give an idea to work around:

Here we try to use the Azure CLI commands `az acr repository list` and `az acr repository show-tags` to include image tags in a loop.

```
SOURCE_REGISTRY=myregistry
TARGET_REGISTRY=targetregistry

# Get list of source repositories
REPOS =  $(az acr repository list \  --name $SOURCE_REGISTRY --output tsv)

# Enumerate tags and import to target registry
for repo in $REPOS; do
    TAGS= $(az acr repository show-tags --name $OURCE_REGISTRY  --repository $repo --output tsv);

    for tag in $TAGS; do
        echo "Importing $repo:$tag";
        az acr import --name $TARGET_REGISTRY --source $SOURCE_REGISTRY /$repo":"$tag  --username <username>   --password <password>  ;
    done
done
```

also please check the  Azure PowerShell equivalents as in Reference: [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/manual-regional-move#import-registry-content-in-target-registry) and almost similar to [Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67749357/how-to-import-all-images-from-an-acr-repository-to-another-acr-in-different-tena)

**References:**

1. [Moving docker images from one container registry to another | by Paulo Gomes | Medium](https://medium.com/@pjbgf/moving-docker-images-from-one-container-registry-to-another-2f1f1631dc49)
2. [container-registry-import-images | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-import-images?tabs=azure-cli#import-from-a-non-azure-private-container-registry)

Comment: Thanks for your Reply, but the az acr commands are for the Azure container registry, what i want is to list the images and tags from gitlab registry not acr